# Badges on Meta vs Main

Tags: support, badges, meta

Since the Meta site does not maintain a reputation, certain badges related to reputation (like [Epic](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/42/epic) and [Legendary](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/43/legendary) are unavailable.

1. Which other [Meta badges](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges) are (un-)attainable?
2. For the unattainable ones, why do they still appear under the list of Meta badges?

Comment: See [Remove impossible badges from per-site metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121922) on [metase].

Comment: @doncherry: Thanks. Seems like I'm *only* 10 months behind...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Reputation related badges

Reputation on meta isn't shown, so it's hard to see what happens. Reputation related badges can be achieved, as several people got the Mortarboard badge. Nobody has Epic or Legendary yet, but it should be possible as well.

---

Badges which we cannot get on meta:

### Bounty related badges

You cannot start a bounty on meta because of missing reputation system.

- Altruist
- Benefactor
- Investor
- Promoter

### Chat badges

It seems that the chat is considered only for the main site.

- Outspoken
- Talkative

meta.SO has its own chat, so there are people with such meta badges.

### Site proposal badges

- Beta
- Precognitive

Those badges were not given at the start of the site, and now it's too late.

Comment: @Werner: thanks for the edit. However, Mortarboard is available, several users got it. Which lets me think, the other rep badges might be attainable too. Now I saw Epic and Legendary on meta.SO.

Comment: You're right... and now I don't know what to believe anymore. My assumption is that the entire meta structure is inherited from "the source" ([Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)), since reputation exists there. Borrowing from the super structure allows for possible incorporation in the future without any adaptation. Being the first that obtained [Mortarboard](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/badges/41/mortarboard), what's the secret? ;)

Comment: @Werner I guess the secret is just activity on meta, then it may happen at some time. I just don't remember why it happened. Questions with several answers (my first thought), such as for the community ads or the poll question cannot count, as they are CW.

Comment: ...I just earned [Mortarboard](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/badges/41/mortarboard), meaning I must have earned "200 reputation" somehow.

Comment: Relevant: [“Mortarboard” continues to be awarded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251249/914686)

Comment: The [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/168244) actually lists all the badges that are *not* attainable on per-meta sites explicitly.