# Reputation acquired in meta does not count

Tags: support, reputation, meta

Since the beginning of the month, my reputation acquired in meta website is not taken into account. When someone vote up one of my question/answer, there is no reputation update. Before I was not using meta.

Is there a possible explanation or is there a bug? What can I do to "refresh" my profile?

Comment: This is by design. From the [Meta Help](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta): "Votes on meta do not affect your reputation;"

Comment: @Jake Good to know. I'm interested to know why this design. Is it to avoid polemical posts to have repercussion to reputation?

Comment: Knowing the site better is a matter of affinity but answering the questions is a matter of authority on the subject. So things discussed here more for the house-keeping, bugs, feature requests etc. More of a site usage focus if you will. I think the points are only for getting recognition by technical answers. Though I still don't know why we have points anyway.

Comment: oh and if your reputation changes on the main site it takes some time for meta to update your rep points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned, this is a [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design).

This has also been raised on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60693/168244), where the answer points to a blog entry by Jeff Attwood called [New Per-Site Metas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/); an introduction to per-site metas across the entire network (July 2010):

> **Reputation is always inherited from the parent site.** You cannot gain or lose reputation* on the per-site meta. This also means that some reputation related functions like the rep graph and bounties are not enabled on the per-site meta.
>
> <sup>* however, there is one exception: extreme misbehavior on the meta site will affect your parent site reputation. And not in, shall we say, the “good” way.</sup>

[Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) is considered different (and separate) from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) since it actually addresses network-wide meta-related content, rather that SO-related/specific content.

Having said all this, [it is still possible to obtain reputation-related badges on per-site metas](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3120/5764). For example, here's a list of [Mortarboard badge earners](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard) to date:

[image]

I think the motivation behind this is that, eventually, there may be a possibility to switch per-meta sites over to full-fledges sites.